# Looking for a good documentation format

Tags: documentation

I have a quite big hobby project and I'm trying not to get lost so I'm off course documenting, might it be "design docs" or "manuals" but I haven't yet found a good format, all my docs are spread out in .txt .doc .odt etc,  maybe you can help me out :-) ?

The really best would be a format with:

- One file only (not html for example)
- Easy to add images, big/small/bold/underlined/... texts.
- Simple to use (no need to 'compile', no need for a gas-powered-editor / simplicity to edit)
- A collapsible 'index' preferably on the left side
- Can be (easily) read on several computers (PC is a must but it would be nice if it works on Mac etc.)
- Free or not very expensive (at least a free and good reader)

I have already tried .odt, powerpoint and .pdf but they have obvious issues (odt: no index, ptt: expensive and PC only, pdf: has it all I think but no (good) free editor ).

What do you use when you are documenting and do you have an idea about a format that would suit me?

Thanks!

[edit] Actually I found out that Open Office text document using different titles and exported to pdf automatically makes bookmarks (for the titles, collapsible too) so that is what I searched for.
As the question got closed with only one answer (thanks! but it wasn't what I was looking for) I can't answer my question and I'll just let it be...

Comment: Well that was nice, -1 after 30 seconds and without any kind of comment...

Comment: I haven't tried Markdown but if I understand correctly you need Pearl to run it, I can live with that but you also need it to read it or else there will be the "1.000 html files" you need to update / make downloadable etc. and that is one reason I'm not using html.

Comment: Markdown runs with Python, PERL, PHP, C++, and virtually any language you can think of. Look at my answer and see for yourself how readable Markdown is. All you do is edit the Markdown *source* file and the parser will spit out formatted text (HTML).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Markdown? That's how I write all of my lengthy articles and such, as Markdown is extremely readable by itself (that's the whole point) and can be edited via any text editor. But with a template engine (I use Jinja2), you can spit out uniform groups of text documents quite well.

- Here's [a sample article](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ECkCEMBP) written in Markdown.
- And the [resulting HTML file](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~nikitan/articles/gnome2/).
- And the [global template file](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zDNW55yw).

If you want to see some examples of the syntax, Wikipedia has a nice article on it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown#Syntax_examples.

Comment: Except for the 'must have pearl' or use html, can you, easily, make a 'left side' index?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?

Comment: Yes but the need to script and that global template file make it seem 'not so easy to edit' though.

Comment: The output is not the input. What you see is the formatted output, while the input is similar to what I linked to in my answer.